# django Decimal('0.0) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django

I have a view :

```
data = {}
data["prize"] = prize # which is a decimal value
data["amount"] = amount # which is a decimal value

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

When I do this it gives me error saying

```
Decimal('9.3') is not JSON serializable
```

Whats wrong in here ?